# Fresh Magento 2.3.0 installation no CSS

Tags: magento2, css, installation

Just installed Magento 2 on a shared server, everything seemed successful, no errors, but the shop looks like this (css files not found, they return 403 Forbidden, but the files are actually missing):

[image]

**It seems like the static content/css is not generated.**

pub/static:
[image]

The only file in pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/locale is **requirejs-config.js**, but there were supposed to also be other files, such as those CSS files:
[image]

I tried reinstalling it, changing folder permissions, different PHP version, nothing worked. It's strange that some folders are generated (also the requirejs file), but not the CSS.

How can I make sure the CSS is generated (without shell access) ?

Why would Magento clearly say installation was successful if it couldn't generate the static files? Can I somehow manually copy those static files?

**Specs:**

- PHP Version 7.1
- Magento CE 2.3.0
- Installed on a shared server, only have cPanel access, no shell

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace .htacess files of your 2.3.0 Magento version with Magento 2.2.x version .htaccess files in following directories.

1. root
2. Pub
3. Pub/static

Comment: Thanks, will try that. Already tried 2-3 different .htaccess versions, but all of them were for 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

try to execute the command from root of magento 2 directory to regenerate static content

`php bin/magento s:s:d -f`

Comment: I don't have shell access, it's a shared hosting.